# How to turn off order of the line graph in plotly Python?

Tags: python, plotly

I want to create a line chart using Plotly. I have 3 variables(date,shift,runt).I want to include date with runt(also i want to display shift as well).

Dataframe:
[image]

What I want is to plot a line chart using both **date** and **shift** to x-axis.
This is what i got from excel. i want to plot a same graph in python

[image]

But I can't take two values.I tried to concatenate the date and shift to one column. But it shows first day values and then night values.

[image]

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df, x="Day-Shift", y="RUNT", title='Yo',template="plotly_dark")
fig.show()
```

Is there any way to turn off order. what i want is shown in the above excel graph

Answer (score 0):

I've created a column that combines the date and the shift and specified it on the x-axis. Does this meet the intent of your question?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Date Shift RUNT
0 June-16 Day 350
1 June-16 Night 20
2 June-17 Day 350
3 June-17 Night 20
4 June-18 Day 350
5 June-18 Night 20
6 June-19 Day 350
7 June-19 Night 20
8 June-20 Day 350
9 June-20 Night 20
10 June-21 Day 350
11 June-21 Night 20
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df['Day-Shift'] = df['Date'].str.cat(df['Shift'], sep='-')

import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df, x="Day-Shift", y="RUNT", title='Yo',template="plotly_dark")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: cant undestand why is that? i run the same.it work with your data.but when I put my data as the exact same format as you, it didn't work

Comment: Check the data format of the x-axis. In my case, it's joined by a string. You can check it by `print(type(df['Day-Shift']))`.

Comment: i find the problem. i have around 60 data points. your solutions didn't work when it has more data points,can you please check it with more data points?

Comment: I created the graph again with 60 data. I don't think it's the number of data that matters.